# awk-IF...ELSE IF issue in command

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk

```
cat file1
xizaoshuijiao @E0488_5@
chifandaqiu @E0488_3@
gongzuoyouxi @E0977_5@

cat file2

@E0488_3@ @E0488_3@
@E0488_5@ @E0488_5@
@E0977_3@ @E0977_3@
@E0977_5@ @E0977_5@
@E0977_6@ @E0977_6@
```

Purpose:if $NF in file1 found in file2 $1, than replace $NF in file1 with file2 $2.otherwise, makes no change.

My code:

```
awk '\
NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;b[$2]=$2;next}\
{if($NF in a)\
    {$NF=b[FNR];print $0}\
else if!($NF in a)\
    {print $0}\
}' file2 file1
```

Then it came error:

```
awk: cmd. line:5: else if!($NF in a)\
awk: cmd. line:5:        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:6:     {print $0}\
awk: cmd. line:6:     ^ syntax error
```

So it seems that "!" issue. because I want to print all content in file1(both changed line and unchanged line).How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can rewrite it in this form

```
awk 'NR==FNR  {a[$1]=$2; next}
     $NF in a {$2=a[$1]}1' file2 file1
```

since your file2 has the same values for $1 and $2, it seems useless.

Since you want to print unconditionally, don't print in the condition block.  Here `1` corresponds to `{print}` which is the same as `{print $0}`

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
if!($NF in a)
```

With:

```
if(!($NF in a))
```

`!` is part of the test-condition and awk expects the test-condition to all be inside parens.

Comment: you need to add another parenthesis otherwise it means `(!$NF) in a`

Comment: Thanks.  Answer updated.  And, separately, I see that you have put together a good & complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes my code after verification.

```
awk '\
NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;b[$2]=$2;next}\
{if($NF in a)\
   {$NF=b[FNR];print $0}\
else         # use else... it will work, no need else if... , but why ? How can I achieve it with else if !($NF in a)
   {print $0}\
}' file2 file1
```

Comment: It might be more succinct/clear if you add this in an *edit* section at the bottom of 
 your question instead of as an answer.